# Excel summing values of one column when the values of another column are the same

Tags: excel

I have seen similar questions on here but still am confused. I have a large amount of data with a column for product number and sales amount. Is there away to sum the rows with the same product number? i have tried the match function but I am missing something. here is an example of what it looks like:

```
Product    value    (need a column here)
0012         12
0012         13   
0113         3
0123         2
0123         23
etc.         etc.
```

Comment: Look into `SUM` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is this an Excel question or a MySQL question? (Note the original question had both tags and I don't think the OP removed the Excel tag.)

Comment: You should try a pivot table - it will show the sum for each uniq value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in Excel.

Assume that "Product" is in cell A1.  You can use conditional summation.  Type the following in C2

```
=sumif($A$2:$A$10000, "="&$A2, $B$2:$B$10000)
```

The number `10000` is just a place holder for the end of the list.

Copy this formula down the column of C, however far you want to go.